# Как создать текстовый документ с названием имя компьютера?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

как сделать, чтобы в название текстового файла автоматически создавалось из имени компьютера, например
lshw > pcname.txt

Comment: Вначале опишите, что вы понимаете под именем компьютера. Я сходу назову как минимум два разных имени одного и того же компьютера.

Comment: то, что пишется после @ в консоли

Comment: Ну это не постоянные данные. Вы получаете только «текущее» имя, которое может меняться, например, при подключении в разные сети.

Answer (score 3):

Это делается просто (если у вас bash или совместимый SHELL):

```
lshw > `hostname`.txt
```

здесь `hostname` — команда, выводящая имя компьютера.

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто:

```
touch `hostname`.txt
```

А lshw、в отличие от touch, не является стандартной утилитой, что может ограничить возможности применения решения.

Comment: hostname тоже есть не везде: `$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname).txt`

Comment: @eri, ну раз пошла такая пьянка, то и упомянутое вами не всюду есть.

Comment: А почему вы решили, имя компьютера — это вывод *hostname*?